# Angular 6 and DRF Django Social authentication

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm using Angular 6 for the front-end and for the back-end I have Django. I connect the front-end and back-end with Django Rest Framework. I need to implement social authentication with (Google, Facebook, LinkedIn). right now I'm using angular-6-social-login. But I don't know how to implement it in the back-end.

Comment: https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

Comment: You could also look into using Django's allauth package as an alternative, I've used this in the past and have been happy with it: https://www.intenct.nl/projects/django-allauth/

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

use this package https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

It is one of the packages listed on the Django Rest Framework documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-oauth-toolkit